# Rank books with ties

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query so far, which works perfectly to rank the books based on our internal score.

```
UPDATE CER
SET CER.book_rank = Ranker.ranc
FROM book_ranks CER
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Rank() over (Order by book_score desc, book_id) as ranc, book_id
FROM book_ranks
WHERE Category = 'Fiction'
GROUP BY book_id, book_score 
) Ranker
ON
CER.book_id = Ranker.book_id
```

The code is working perfect, but not taking care of case.

Input:

```
bookName  book_score
--------  ----------
book2     45
book3     35
book5     35
book7     35
book9     30
```

Current Output:

```
bookName  book_score  book_rank
--------  ----------  ---------
book2     45          1
book3     35          2
book5     35          3
book7     35          4
book9     30          5
```

Required Output:

```
bookName  book_score  book_rank
--------  ----------  ---------
book2     45          1
book3     35          2
book5     35          2
book7     35          2
book9     30          5
```

As book3, book5, book7 has the same score, their rank should be same and book9 should have rank of 5.

Comment: Why do you want to store the rank, when you could simply calculate it at run time? If you store the rank, you have to update the whole table every time any row changes.

Comment: Also please don't format input using HTML etc. Just highlight code or tabular results using the `{}` button. It's quite a mess to clean up otherwise.

Comment: Hello Mr. Aaron, the reason for scoring the rank is as we have thousands of records and we need the ranks in many pages. About HTML, I looked for the options and didn't find, so ended up using HTML. I will keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM book_ranks CER
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Rank() over (Order by book_score desc  ) 
  -- only difference is here ----------------^^
  as ranc, book_id
  FROM book_ranks
  WHERE Category = 'Fiction'
GROUP BY book_id, book_score 
) Ranker
ON CER.book_id = Ranker.book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SELECT Rank() over (Order by book_score desc, book_id)
```

You should use

```
SELECT Rank() over (Order by book_score desc)
```

That would solve your problem.